# POST to MongoDB on MongoLab using mongoose and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mlab

I'm trying to add some data to database on mongolab.com
I have a app written using node.js

part of `index.js` is:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var StacjaMeteo = require('./models/StacjaMeteo.js');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:xxxxxxxx@ds041484.mongolab.com:41484/stacjameteo', function(err) {
  if(err) {
    console.log('connection error', err);
  }
  else {
    console.log('connection with database successful');
  }
});


app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));



app.post('/meteo', function(req, res, next) {
  StacjaMeteo.create(req.body, function(err, post) {
    if(err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  });
});
```

The mongoose model looks like this: `models/StacjaMeteo.js`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var StacjaMeteoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    winddir: Number,
    windspeedmph: Number,
    windgustmph: Number,
    windgustdir: Number,
    humidity: Number,
    tempf: Number,
    pressure: Number,
    updated_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('StacjaMeteo', StacjaMeteoSchema);
```

After lunching the app I got info that connection with database is successful. But when I'm trying to send some data to it using Postman:

```
POST /meteo HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5000
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 39ec83eb-00e9-3e69-875e-ef8f2eaf2b1a
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

winddir=0&windspeedmph=0&windgustmph=0&humidity=0&tempf=0&pressure=0
```

I got the respond:

```
{
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "567012cbc1e781f67706f9ad",
  "updated_at": "2015-12-15T13:16:59.964Z"
}
```

So there is nothing more than just the id and updated_at and nothing new is added to database.

What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didnt tell express how to parse your request body.

In your express configuration , add this two lines

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```

More info on extended keyword : https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#extended

Comment: Thank you! it works, but when running I got sth like this in logs:
`Tue, 15 Dec 2015 18:32:42 GMT body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option at index.js:23:20`
I'm not shure If I understand it...